# Why does my code fail to run in VSCode, but works in Online compiler?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I've written code to add and multiply polynomials using Linked Lists. The code compiles in Online GDB compiler, but fails on VS Code.
Can someone clarify why this is happening?
I feel that the issue is somewhere with the while loops, but cant find it exactly.
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NODES 2 // NODES > 0 

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    int power;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *create_list()
{
    node *head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    int n;
    int data, power;
    printf("For node 1:\n");
    printf("Enter coefficient: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    printf("Enter power: ");
    scanf("%d", &power);
    node *new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node -> data = data;
    new_node -> power = power;
    head = new_node;
    
    for(n = 0; n < NODES - 1; n++)
    {
        printf("For node %d:\n", n+2);
        printf("Enter coefficient: ");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        printf("Enter power: ");
        scanf("%d", &power);
        node *new = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        new -> data = data;
        new -> power = power;
        new_node -> next = new;
        new_node = new;
    }
    return head;
}

void display(node *head)
{
    while(head -> next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%dx^(%d) + ", head-> data, head -> power);
        head = head -> next;
    }
    printf("%dx^(%d)\n", head -> data, head -> power);
}

int is_in(int data, node *list)
{
    // if power in list, return 1, else 0
    while(list != NULL)
    {
        if(list -> power == data)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        list = list -> next;
    }
    return 0;
}

node *simplify(node *head)
{
    node *p1 = head;
    node *p2 = head -> next;
    int coefficient, power;
    node *output = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *temp = output;
    while(p1 != NULL)
    {
        p2 = p1 -> next;
        int sum = p1 -> data;
        if(!is_in(p1 -> power, output) || (p1 -> power == 0 && !is_in(0, output -> next)))
        {
            while(p2 != NULL)
            {
                if(p2 -> power == p1 -> power)
                    sum += p2 -> data;
                p2 = p2 -> next;
            }
            node *new = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            new -> data = sum;
            new -> power = p1 -> power;
            temp -> next = new;
            temp = temp -> next;
        }
        p1 = p1 -> next;
    }
    return output -> next;
}

node *add_remaining_nodes_from_head(node *head3, node *head)
{
    node *temp1 = head3;
    node *temp2 = head;
    
    while(temp1 -> next != NULL)
    {
        temp1 = temp1 -> next;
    }
    
    while(temp2 != NULL)
    {
        if(!is_in(temp2 -> power, head3) || (temp2 -> power == 0 && !is_in(0, head3 -> next)))//if temp2 -> power is not in head3
        {
            node *new = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            new -> data = temp2 -> data;
            new -> power = temp2 -> power;
            temp1 -> next = new;
            temp1 = temp1 -> next;
        }
        temp2 = temp2 -> next;   
    }
    
    return head3;
}

node *add(node *head1, node *head2)
{
    node *head3 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("\nAdding Lists:\n");
    display(head1);
    display(head2);
    printf("\n");

    node *p1 = head1;
    node *p2 = head2;
    node *p3 = head3;

    while(p1 != NULL)
    {
        p2 = head2;
        int power, coefficient;
        power = p1 -> power;
        while(p2 != NULL)
        {
            if(p2 -> power == power)
            {
                node *new = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
                new -> data = p1 -> data + p2 -> data;
                new -> power = power;
                p3 -> next = new;
                p3 = p3 -> next;
            }
            p2 = p2 -> next;
        }
        p1 = p1 -> next;
    }

    head3 = add_remaining_nodes_from_head(head3, head1);
    head3 = add_remaining_nodes_from_head(head3, head2);
    
    return head3 -> next;
}

node *multiply(node *head1, node *head2)
{
    node *head3 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("\nMultiplying Lists:\n");
    display(head1);
    display(head2);
    printf("\n");

    node *p1 = head1;
    node *p2 = head2;
    node *p3 = head3;
    
    while(p1)
    {
        p2 = head2;
        while(p2)
        {
            int coefficient, power;
            coefficient = p1 -> data * p2 -> data;
            power = p1 -> power + p2 -> power;
            node *new = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            new -> data = coefficient;
            new -> power = power;
            p3 -> next = new;
            p3 = new;
            p2 = p2 -> next;
        }
        p1 = p1 -> next;
    }
    
    return head3 -> next;
}

int main()
{
    printf("First List:\n");
    node *head1 = create_list();
    printf("Second List:\n");
    node *head2 = create_list();
    
    printf("\nOriginal Lists: \n");
    
    display(head1);
    display(head2);

    head1 = simplify(head1);
    head2 = simplify(head2);
    
    node *head_add = add(head1, head2);
    printf("Answer: \n");
    display(head_add);

    node *head_multiply = multiply(head1, head2);
    printf("Answer: \n");
    display(head_multiply);
    printf("\nSimplified Answer: \n");
    head_multiply = simplify(head_multiply);
    display(head_multiply);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output in Vscode:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3a7C.png

Comment: This usually means there are bugs in your code. And when that happens the thing to do is to debug it. Run your program in a debugger and examine it as it executes. One problem is that `new->next` is not set for the last node in `create_list` and is likely contributing to if not the exact cause of your problem.

Comment: If you are routinely going to forget to initialize all elements in an allocated structure, then consider using `calloc` instead to be safe.

Comment: [There are definitely bugs](https://godbolt.org/z/56b883PEq) in `create_list` or `display`

Comment: [To get you started](https://godbolt.org/z/3TEa59jMa) Note the use of `-fsanitize=address`. `simplify` should modify the list in-place, deleting the duplicates it finds.

Comment: Works Now! Thank You to all. I believe I had to point the last nodes of the lists to NULL.